# Go to particular Route's div element

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two routes. From one route I need to get another route's div element by button click. I done a similar way with `id(#)` that we do in HTML but It's not working out. Can you suggest a best way to do in Angular>

**Route One (/route1)**

```
<div class="div1">
<p>hi</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
<p>hello</p>
</div>
```

**Route two (/route2)**

```
<button (click)="getDiv()"></button>
```

**TS**

```
getDiv()
{
      this.router.navigate(['/route1']); // I need to get div1 of route1 here
}
```

Comment: So you basically want to do an anchor link using routing? If yes, that's not how route works.

Comment: By `this.router.navigate(['/route1']);` , we can go to particular route know. So, Is there is any way to get the div of that route is what I am asking

Comment: You could send the id of the div as `param` and handle the scrolling on your target component

Comment: `gotodiv(id) { const element = document.getElemnetById(id);
if (element)  { element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' }); } }`

Comment: This is typescript

Comment: @FelixChristo you can import the document  using `import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';` and the inject  the same into constructor  `constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}`

Comment: if you are trying to scroll to a div the above code will help you  , you can write the logic  necessary for the route  and then after moving to the route,  to scroll  to particulate div you can use these function just by passing the id of the div

Comment: But `scrollIntoView` is for same page know? I want to navigate to another route's div

Comment: that what i mentioned  you need to use `[routerLink]="['/route1' ]"` and  pass the id  to the next component  and after that call the function `gotodiv(id)`. you can  check in ngOnInt to see  id is passed  and if id is passed then call the function to scroll to div

Comment: Blogged on the same https://medium.com/@PardeepJain/deep-dive-into-angular-routing-scrolling-to-top-debugging-and-lot-more-a995c08498d3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using angular 6.1+ version you can enable anchorScrolling manually

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot(route,{
       anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
  }) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Then specifies the id on the div which you want to scroll to

**router-a.component.ts**

```
<div class="div1"  id="div1">
<p>Div1</p>
</div>

<div class="div2" id="div2" >
<p>Div2</p>
</div>
```

Finall Use fragment to navigate to the current div location

```
getDiv() {
    this.router.navigate(['/route2'], { fragment: 'div2' });
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h7bvyu

Answer (score -1):

your html should be in a different module and routing should be configured. Using the following code in the html would don the same routing.

```
<button [routerLink]="['/route1']">View All</button>
```

your router should be configured with the root.

Comment: I want to go to `/route1` 's particular div not `/route1`

Comment: you have to add that div into another module and do the routing separately. You can't route to specific div in the same html via route. Just use ngif to show hide that div for the click action.