# Using fragment in angular 7 route

Tags: angular, routes

I have read the documentation for fragments in angular routing but I must be not understanding. I have a standard material sidenav on which I am trying to use links like this

```
<a  class="mat-toobar-link" routerLink="/" fragment="section3">Section3</a>
```

where section3 looks like

```
  <div #section3 id="section3" class="section">Section 3</div>
```

The link adds the fragment correctly to the url in the browser address bar ('http://localhost:4200/#section3') but no actual navigation takes place.

I am aware that many other people have had this problem but in my research I have seen only hints at answers that are incomplete or flat out don't work.

I assume that scrollToElement() can be used in some way but can't imagine how this would be set up.

Can anyone provide a comprehensive solution to this problem I'm having?

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062285/go-to-particular-routes-div-element/55063036#55063036