# How to redirect to particular section of div in angular page component

Tags: angular

How to redirect to particular section of div in angular page component on saving i have to redirect certain div of a page
 this.router.navigate(['dashboard/operations/events']);

Comment: what do you mean I want to redirect a div ? IF you redirect you redirect the browser to another page. If you want a div to display some content on saving, that you just make a component that appear on that div whilse saving

Comment: do you mean , you want to go to a div with special ``Id`` like : dashboard/operation/events#div-id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to particular Route's div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062285/go-to-particular-routes-div-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Welcome</title>
  </head
  <body>
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <p>
        <i>Redirect to a particular div section in the same page</i>
      </p>
      <a href="#home"> Home </a>
      <a href="#about"> About Us </a>
      <a href="#contact"> Contact Us </a>

      <br/>

      <div id="home">
        <h2>Home section</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="about">
        <h2>About Us section</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="contact">
        <h2>Contact Us section </h2>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).